# How does $(2k+1)^2$ become $4k^2 + 4k + 1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm currently following a course where the professor did the following simple calculation:

$$(2k+1)^2 = 4k^2 + 4k + 1$$

Now, I just do not understand any world where this can be the case.
Could someone please explain to me why $(2k+1)\times(2k+1)$ can ever result in only one $1$, and reduced to $2k$?

This is so extremely nonsennsical for me.

Comment: Have you ever FOILed before? That is, do you know how to expand $(A+B)(C+D)$ using the distributive property?

Comment: $(a+b)(c+d)=ac+ad+bc+bd$

Comment: $(a+b)^2 = a^2+2ab+b^2$.

Comment: ah yes i see thanks

Comment: foil is exactly what i was looking for

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 5):

Recall the distribution property:

$$a(b+c) = ab + ac$$

In this case, we can distribute the factor of $2k+1$:

$$(2k+1)^2 = (2k+1)(2k+1) = (2k+1)2k + (2k+1)1$$

You can already at this point see why we would have $1$ as your constant: the first term will have $k$'s in it because of the $2k$ factor, while the latter term is just $2k+1$, explaining where the $1$ comes from.

---

You could alternatively use the formula for squaring a binomial:

$$(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$$

Then, in $(2k+1)^2$, $a=2k,b=1$:

$$(2k+1)^2 = (2k)^2 + 2(2k)(1) + (1)^2 = 4k^2 + 4k + 1$$

---

Perhaps a diagram? Imagine a square of width $2k+1$. You can visualize it as so:

[image]

The area of this square is obviously $(2k+1)^2$, right? If you add up the area of each rectangle however, you'll get $4k^2 + 4k +1$, establishing equality between the two expressions.

Comment: This is very well explained (+1).

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more complicated, but more generalizable. Binomial Theorem.

$(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^ky^{n-k}$

Where $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

So if $n=2$ then

$(x+y)^n=\binom{2}{0}x^0y^2+\binom{2}{1}x^1y^2+\binom{2}{2}x^2y^0=x^2+2xy+y^2$

Then let $x=2k$ and $y=1$.

$(2k+1)^2=(2k)^2+2(2k)(1)+1^2=4k^2+4k+1$